# Angular localForage return [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, localforage

After setting a key/value by 'setItem' (and checked if the items is stored correctly) I'm trying to get the value of the key. Instead of getting the correct value, I get the following respons: `[object Promise]`

```
return localforage.getItem('test', function(err, value) {
        console.log(value);
        return value;
      });
```

Checking the console shows me the correct value I set via setItem. So, the console.log (but also an alert) is giving me the correct value. Returning the value gives me a promise: `{[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

Comment: So? It's asynchronous. Use the promise.

Comment: Hi Bergi, that sounds like easy-to-understand answer and probably it is, but Promises are quite new to me. I did some research to understand them, but couldn't match it with the localforage result I get. For me, it is a bit strange the result is displaying the correct value if I print them via console.log() but the return value is a Promise with an undefined PromiseValue.

Edit:
Is it correct the only way of getting the value is to return `localforage.getItem(key)` in the function and treat the respons like a Promise: `respons = lf.getItem('test'); respons.then(function(value) {  });` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. The `console.log` will only show the value inside the callback.

Comment: Ok, great! thanks for your help!